# Java Based on this input, the program will display the number of integers in less than 50

Tags: java, arrays, parameters

for the task i need to Write a Java application that accepts 30 integer numbers from the user. The input should be in the range of 1-200. Error message needs to be displayed if user entered input which is not in this range. Based on this input, the program will display the number of integers entered in the following categories: 
   Less than 50 
   Between 50-100 (inclusive of 50 and 100)

Sample output :
Enter number 4: 211

Input error..Pls enter number between 1 to 200 only

Enter number 4: 20

..

..

Enter number 30: 90

Less than 50: 12

Between 50-100 (inclusive of 50 and 100): 8

Between 101-150 (inclusive of 101 and 150): 5

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Keyboard Initialization
        Scanner kbin = new Scanner(System.in);

        // a.Declare an array to hold 5 Integer values
        int list[] = new int[5];
        int i = 0;

        System.out.print("\n\tInput numbers from 1 to 200: \n");
        while (i < 5) {
            // b.Fill the array with intgers from the keyboard(range: 1 to 200).
            System.out.print("Enter Integer" + (i + 1) + ":");
            int value = kbin.nextInt();

            if (value >= 1 && value <= 200) {
                list[i] = value;
                i++;
            } else {
                System.out.println("!! Error! Please Enter Value between 1 and 200 !!");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some more information? Like what's the purpose of your program and why doesn't it do what you want it to do?

Comment: It seems you've completed tasks `a` and `b` already. Can you show us what you've tried for the task you're asking about?

Comment: Hi Guys, for the task i need to  Write a Java application that accepts 30 integer numbers from the user. The input should be in the range of 1-200. Error message needs to be displayed if user entered input which is not in this range. Based on this input, the program will display the number of integers in the following categories:

 Less than 50
 Between 50-100 (inclusive of 50 and 100)

Comment: I'm unable to figure out how to use the Method to produce the Number of input entered

Comment: why are you using an array of size 5?

Comment: Its a test program mate. I'm testing using 5 values first

Comment: What's the problem? You have counter `i`, add similar counters and increment them if `value` safisfies your condition

Comment: Add what you have given in the comments about the overall requirements of the program to the question @DilipKalebere.

Comment: Added mate. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is an example using Java Streams. Here we simply read all the values first, then filter out each category later. Performance wise, it's better to just use a counter for each category if you don't care about the actual numbers being counted though.

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int counter = 0;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();

    while (counter < 5) {
      System.out.print("Enter integer (" + (counter + 1) + "): ");
      int value = scanner.nextInt();

      if (value >= 1 && value <= 200) {
        counter++;
        values.add(value);
      } else {
        System.out.println("Please enter a value between 1 and 200");
      }
  }
  System.out.println("Between 1-50   : " + values.stream().filter(val -> val < 50).count());
  System.out.println("Between 50-100 : " + values.stream().filter(val -> val >= 50 && val <= 100).count());
  System.out.println("Between 101-150: " + values.stream().filter(val -> val > 100 && val <= 150).count());
  System.out.println("Between 151-200: " + values.stream().filter(val -> val > 150 && val <= 200).count());
}
```

Output example:

```
Enter integer (1): 5
Enter integer (2): 55
Enter integer (3): 125
Enter integer (4): 175
Enter integer (5): -2
Please enter a value between 1 and 200
Enter integer (5): 201
Please enter a value between 1 and 200
Enter integer (5): 199
Between 1-50   : 1
Between 50-100 : 1
Between 101-150: 1
Between 151-200: 2
```

Comment: OP has clearly mentioned in the question that he needs 4 categories.. Your code just categorizes into 3, not 4. Where do the numbers between 150 and 200 go?

Comment: I'm happy to add it, but the fourth category is not mentioned anywhere by OP.

Comment: @Rai stop following this user around commenting and downvoting. It's harassment

Answer (score -1):

It is a very simple problem here @Dilip. Just introduce a `flag` variable which would mark if an input is wrong. If it is, then just accept the value again. Else proceed. 
Following is the code snippet for the input part also considering the wrong and right input boundaries.

```
        System.out.print("\n\tInput numbers from 1 to 200: \n");
        for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
          flag = 0;
          while(flag == 0) {
            list[i] = kbin.nextInt();
            if(!(list[i] < 1 || list[i] > 200)){
              flag = 1;
            }
            else {
              System.out.println("INVALID INPUT!!! Enter a valid number.");
            }
          }
        }
```

I have gone through the problem statement which you have told about in the comments section and have coded the program which would serve the purpose. I have also attached the output for confirmation and reference. Hope this helps.

**CODE:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Keyboard Initialization
        Scanner kbin = new Scanner(System.in);

        // a.Declare an array to hold 5 Integer values
        int list[] = new int[5];
        int category1[] = new int[5], k1 = 0;
        int category2[] = new int[5], k2 = 0;
        int category3[] = new int[5], k3 = 0;
        int i, flag;

        System.out.print("\n\tInput numbers from 1 to 200: \n");
        for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
          flag = 0;
          while(flag == 0) {
            System.out.print("Enter the input number " + (i+1) + ": ");
            list[i] = kbin.nextInt();
            if(!(list[i] < 1 || list[i] > 200)){
              flag = 1;
            }
            else {
              System.out.println("INVALID INPUT!!! Enter a valid number.");
            }
          }
        }

        for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
          if(list[i] < 50)
            category1[k1++] = list[i];
          else if(list[i] < 101)
            category2[k2++] = list[i];
          else
            category3[k3++] = list[i];
        }

        System.out.print("Category 1(1 TO 49): ");System.out.println(k1);
    System.out.print("Category 2(50 TO 100): ");
    System.out.println(k2);
    System.out.print("Category 3(greater than 100): ");
    System.out.println(k3);
    System.out.print("Category 4(151 to 200): ");
    System.out.println(k4);
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

> ```
>   Input numbers from 1 to 200: 
> Enter the input number 1:  2
> Enter the input number 2:  3
> Enter the input number 3:  50
> Enter the input number 4:  56
> Enter the input number 5:  159
> Category 1(1 TO 49): 2
> Category 2(50 TO 100): 2
> Category 3(101 to 150): 0
> Category 4(151 to 200): 1
> ```

Comment: Hi mate, thanks for the help but the output for the category should be as below. As it should show the number of input entered for each category. That is where im stuck at.. Mind if can assist on it
The output for the category  should be like this:
Less than 50: 1

Between 50-100 (inclusive of 50 and 100): 2

Comment: Okay @DilipKalebere. done.. i have updated.. but what about numbers from 101 to 200? I have given it as a category 3... if not needed, just make it as a comment.

Comment: Great mate. The solution i've been looking up for past hours. Thanks for the assistance. Appreciate it.

Comment: Why would you use both arrays and counters for the categories? It makes no sense to do both. In this case the counter is enough.

Comment: @Rai: Wow. No need to get so defensive. I did not downvote you... That said, this code has a lot of room to improve :)